# React TypeScript - Button Onclick Triggered When Rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, onclick, onclicklistener

I have problems with rendering a button with onClick function, as whenever I try to render it, the onClick on the button always triggered.

This is the block of code that render the components:

```
                  <Table.Body>
                    {productNames.map((value, index) => {
                      return (
                        <Table.Row key={index}>
                          <Table.Cell>
                            <label>
                              {index}
                            </label>
                          </Table.Cell>
                          <Table.Cell>
                            <label>
                              {value}
                            </label>
                          </Table.Cell>
                          <Table.Cell>
                            <Button color="red" onClick={() => removeProduct(index) as any}>
                              Remove Product
                            </Button>
                          </Table.Cell>  
                        </Table.Row>
                        
                      )
                    })}
                  </Table.Body>
```

This is my remove product function:

```
  function removeProduct(index: number) {
    const productArray: string[] = productNames;
    productArray.splice(index, 1);
    setProductNames(productArray as any);
    console.log("deleted")}
```

This is my full code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { css } from "@emotion/css";
import { Input, Button, Form, Segment, Dropdown, Grid, Icon, Table, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Layout from "../common/Layout";

const inputStyle = css`
  width: 200px;
`;

const sectionStyle = css`
  margin: 1em 1em 0 1em;
`;

const optionStyle = css`
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #d3d3d3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const columnStyle = css`
  max-width: 1600px;
`;

const columnItemStyle = css`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 5px;
`;

const buttonStyle = css`
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: 15px;
`;

const CreateDomainPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [domainName, setDomainName] = useState("");
  const [productNamesFieldValue, setProductNamesFieldValue] = useState("");
  const [productNames, setProductNames] = useState([]);
  const [quantitiveAttributeNames, setQuantitiveAttributeNames] = useState([]);
  const [qualitativeAttributeNames, setQualitativeAttributeNames] = useState([]);
  const [dateAttributeNames, setDateAttributeNames] = useState([]);
  const [qualitativeValueNames, setQualitativeValueNames] = useState([]);
  const [saveNewDomain, setSaveNewDomain] = useState(false);

  const handleResetButton = () => {
    setDomainName("");
    setProductNames([]);
    setQuantitiveAttributeNames([]);
    setQualitativeAttributeNames([]);
    setDateAttributeNames([]);
    setQualitativeValueNames([]);
  }

  const productOptions = [
    {key: 'a', text: 'Test a', value:'a'},
    {key: 'b', text: 'Test b', value:'b'},
    {key: 'c', text: 'Test c', value:'c'},
    {key: 'd', text: 'Test d', value:'d'},
    {key: 'e', text: 'Test e', value:'e'},
    {key: 'f', text: 'Test f', value:'f'}
  ]

  const options = [
    {key: 'b', text: 'Test a', value:'b'},
    {key: 'a', text: 'Test b', value:'a'},
    {key: 'c', text: 'Test c', value:'c'},
    {key: 'd', text: 'Test d', value:'d'},
    {key: 'e', text: 'Test e', value:'e'},
    {key: 'f', text: 'Test f', value:'f'}
  ]

  function addProduct(productName: string) {
    const productArray: string[] = productNames;
    productArray.push(productName);
    setProductNames(productArray as any);
    setProductNamesFieldValue("");
  }

  function removeProduct(index: number) {
    const productArray: string[] = productNames;
    productArray.splice(index, 1);
    setProductNames(productArray as any);
    console.log("deleted")
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={sectionStyle}>
        <h1>Create a New Domain</h1>
        <Grid centered>
          <Grid.Column className={columnStyle}>
            <Segment>
              <Form>
                <Form.Field>
                  <label>Domain Name :</label>
                  <Input
                    className={inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Domain Name"
                    onChange={(e, {value}) => setDomainName(value)}
                    value={domainName}
                  />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                  <label>Product Names :</label>
                  <Input 
                    className={inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Product Names"
                    onChange={(e, {value}) => setProductNamesFieldValue(value)}
                    value={productNamesFieldValue}
                    onKeyDown={(e: KeyboardEvent) => e.key==="Enter"? addProduct(productNamesFieldValue) : null}
                  />
                  <Segment>
                    <Table celled>
                      <Table.Header>
                        <Table.Row>
                          <Table.HeaderCell>No. </Table.HeaderCell>
                          <Table.HeaderCell>Product Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                          <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                      </Table.Header>

                      <Table.Body>
                        {productNames.map((value, index) => {
                          return (
                            <Table.Row key={index}>
                              <Table.Cell>
                                <label>
                                  {index}
                                </label>
                              </Table.Cell>
                              <Table.Cell>
                                <label>
                                  {value}
                                </label>
                              </Table.Cell>
                              <Table.Cell>
                                <Button color="red" onClick={() => removeProduct(index) as any}>
                                  Remove Product
                                </Button>
                              </Table.Cell>  
                            </Table.Row>
                            
                          )
                        })}
                      </Table.Body>
                    </Table>

                    
                  </Segment>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                  <label>Quantitive Attribute Names :</label>
                  <Dropdown 
                    placeholder="Quantitive Attribute Names" 
                    fluid multiple search selection
                    allowAdditions
                    // onAddItem={(event, data) => options.push({key: data.value as any, text: data.value as any, value: data.value as any})}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={(e, {value}) => setQuantitiveAttributeNames(value as any)} 
                    value={quantitiveAttributeNames}
                  />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                  <label>Qualitative Attribute Names :</label>
                  <Dropdown 
                    placeholder="Qualitative Attribute Names" 
                    fluid multiple search selection
                    allowAdditions
                    // onAddItem={(event, data) => options.push({key: data.value as any, text: data.value as any, value: data.value as any})}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={(e, {value}) => setQualitativeAttributeNames(value as any)} 
                    value={qualitativeAttributeNames}
                  />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                  <label>Date Attribute Names :</label>
                  <Dropdown 
                    placeholder="Date Attribute Names" 
                    fluid multiple search selection
                    allowAdditions
                    // onAddItem={(event, data) => options.push({key: data.value as any, text: data.value as any, value: data.value as any})}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={(e, {value}) => setDateAttributeNames(value as any)} 
                    value={dateAttributeNames}
                  />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                  <label>Qualitative Value Names :</label>
                  <Dropdown 
                    placeholder="Qualitative Value Names" 
                    fluid multiple search selection 
                    allowAdditions
                    // onAddItem={(event, data) => options.push({key: data.value as any, text: data.value as any, value: data.value as any})}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={(e, {value}) => setQualitativeValueNames(value as any)} 
                    value={qualitativeValueNames}
                  />
                </Form.Field>

                <Button color="teal" onClick={() => setSaveNewDomain(true)}>
                  Save Domain
                </Button>
                <Button color="red" onClick={() => handleResetButton()}>
                  Reset
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default CreateDomainPage;
```

How can I avoid this onClick trigger when rendering? I've tried to bind it, but the onClick ended up cannot be triggered at all. I can't use `this` when calling the function inside onClick, I don't know why.

**EDIT**

I found out something weird here, I found out that the problems is actually in the components. I've tried to change it with pure label also with onClick() function, and it works out perfectly.

**EDIT**

Problem solved by adding type="button" to the button.

Comment: Why are you appending `as any` to *everything*?  (If literally *every type* in your code is `any` then stop using TypeScript, just use JavaScript.)  If you remove that from the button click handler, does it change the behavior?

Comment: `I can't use this`   Well you are using arrow functions, so don't have `this`, but even then what do you expect `this` to point too?

Comment: Do you get "deleted" in your console ? On page load?
Do you have any other components that renders that have console.log("deleted") inside? I don't think the code inside removeProduct is actually running on page load...
Also I suggest you read a little bit more on typescript before continueing, also functional components..

Comment: @David well it's actually still a mockup, and I literally don't know which data type that is used later. I've updated it, and removed the any. But it doesn't really change the behaviour.

Comment: @Wings well the "deleted" log is not actually appear when the page is loading. And I don't have other components that produces that log. The removeProduct is actually rendered when I insert a text into the Input component and press enter, and then it render the Table also with that onClick function. While it render the Table, it also triggers the onClick function on the button that I render.

Comment: @Kevin: Would you be able to provide a live, runnable example which demonstrates the issue?  Preferably as a code snippet here, but failing that perhaps something like CodeSandbox?

Answer (score 0):

There is no something wrong with your delete button, I try to run it and the onClick button not triggered, I just edit your `addProduct`, `removeProduct`

```
function addProduct() {
    setProductNames([...productNames, productNamesFieldValue]);
    setProductNamesFieldValue("");
}

function removeProduct(index: number) {
    setProductNames(productNames.filter((_: string, i: number) => i !== index));
    console.log("deleted", index);
}
```

and `Save Domain` button

```
<Button color="teal" onClick={addProduct}>
    Save Domain
</Button>
```

here is the sandbox [click me](https://codesandbox.io/embed/semantic-ui-example-forked-cbx6h7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fexample.js&theme=dark)